# Print 2 characters from a string variable

Tags: python

While learning variables in Python I came across this -
if I define a variable
`name = "Youtube"`

What will be the code if I want to print *t* and *b*?

I know `name[3:6] = "tub"`? But I need to know what do I need to do in order to get *t* and *b* as output.

Comment: To do this, you need to understand how to cut and slice [string](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/). You can access those letters by index or by matching them in a for loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Will learn slicing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, consider not naming a variable *name* (it may confuse you later on).

Two choices for this specific case:

```
x = "Youtube"
>>> print(x[3]+x[5])
tb
```

or

```
>>> print(x[3::2])
tb
```

`"Youtube"[3::2]` means start at index 3 (first index is 0, so position 3 is 't' and from then on every second index until there is nothing left.)

`"Youtuber"[3::2]` would result in 'tbr' instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Loved the detailed explanation and the example. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Strings work the same way as lists in Python.

```
s = "Youtube"
print(s[0])
```

Will show the first thing contained in your string: `Y`

```
print((s[0:2])
```

Will show from first to n-1 (so from 0 to 1) : `Yo`

If you want to print the 'b' and the 't', you need to call :

```
print(s[5]+s[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to skin this cat. [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works) is definitely a starting point.

```
name = "Youtube"
sub = name[3:6]  # "tub"
```

Even more basic is accessing individual elements by index:

```
x = name[3]  # "t"
y = name[5]  # "b"
```

Also helpful, particular to get edge elements, is unpacking:

```
x, _*, y = sub  # will get t and b respectively
```

This does: *of the iterable `sub`, assign the first element to `x`, the last one to `y`, and what ever is in between to an anonymous list `_`*. No need to know the length of `sub` in advance and works with iterators where you wont be able to use slices or negative indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `print(name[3] + name[5])`. That prints the 4th and 6th letter in the string.